# Create new audio file with many little audio snippets

Tags: iphone, audio

I want to put many little audio snippets together to a new one. This should happen randomly - therefore this new big audio file will be unique.

For this reason I need a procedure or a class in the framework which brings me in the ability to perform this task.

I found the classes **AVAssetTrack, AVCompostionTrack, AVMutableCompostionTrack, ...**, in the **AVFoundation-Framework**. It seems that the possibilities with this classes would be able to fulfill my requirements. But they also look pretty complex and I wondered if there is a more simple way to do it. Does someone have a tip for me to bring me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance !
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that the classes of the AVFoundation-Framework are the right ones. After a while of studying them they don't appear that difficult anymore ;-)
I will make it with them...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can complete your task by simply appending new parts to some initial record and updating file's header (if case of pcm format). and don't forget to remove headers from records you are appending.

Comment: I will try it with the AVFoundation-Framework. It seems that there are no real alternatives. (writing in header files is a little bit to pro for me)